# Vertically Aligning Slides Within Slick Slide using Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have done about 2 hours worth of searching, tried over 15 solutions, and none of them have worked. I have a slick-slider as follows:

```
       <section id="testimonial-section" class="pt-4 pb-0 px-4 bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="text-center mb-4">Student Evaluations</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col slide-col">
                        <div class="slider">
                            <div>
                                <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                                    <p class="mb-0">"Text Paragraph 1"</p>
                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                                    <p class="mb-0">"Text paragraph 2."</p>
                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                                    <p class="mb-0">"Text paragraph 3."</p>
                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I need each classless `div` to be vertically centered within the containing slider frame as it shows up on the screen. Right now, these divs are shoved up against the top of the slider, leaving lots of unnecessary room at the bottom.

I have tried using `d-flex` on the slider itself with `align-items-center` and `align-self-center` on each classless `div`.

I have also tried making the `slider` display as inline block and using the `my-auto` command on each classles `div`.

I have also tried using `table cell` to no avail.

These were by far the most common suggestions.

Are there any 'bootstrappy' ways to quickly solve this? Are there any built-in slick-slider ways to solve this? If no to both questions, what is the simplest way to do this?

EDIT: The full `section` has been posted above. No extra CSS or JS is affecting the `section`. There is also a `test1` class on the classless `div`s and the `slider` itself to ascertain what's going wrong, but I left it out here because it won't be a part of the final code. It puts a small red border around the classless div, and the slider div immediately parenting it, producing the following picture (for example):

[image]
As you can see, the classless div is being shoved up against the top of the slider div.

Answer (score 1):

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/webdevdani/pen/KXJqKb

Since you say you have remaining space in the slider, I'm assuming it has a height.

Here's a simple solution with adding just a few Bootstrap4 classes on the slider:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="slider d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div>
          <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
            <p class="mb-0">"This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length."</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div>
          <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
            <p class="mb-0">"This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length.""This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length."</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div>
          <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
            <p class="mb-0">"This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length.""This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length.""This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length.""This is a bunch of random works, and each slide is of varying length."</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styling added in my codepen:

```
.col {
    height: 400px; // Random, taller height for example
}
```

Documentation of added flexbox helper classes: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: My slider did not have a set height. Is that required? I'm worried about responsiveness... EDIT: This does not work for me. Even if I give both the col and the slider a height.

Comment: @JohnnyApple Would you be able to post more of your code please? If there's no room for it to be vertically aligned within, it will just be as tall as the content

Comment: See my heavily revised post. I added a picture of what's wrong, and the full section containing the slider.